# Same ScrollView code does not work in another layout

Tags: android, scrollview

I developed a video call application. But on the messaging screen, my customer asked for a reply function. While developing this, I copied Scrollview's code that I ran in another layout. But the same code doesn't work in another layout?

Here my code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_their_message_ll"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reply_text_view_adapter"
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:text="Reply Message Here"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by doesn't work? what you expect and what you get?

Comment: Depending on your layout, there is nothing to scroll. The textview is the only view in the scroll view.

Comment: @Zain Hey Zain, thanks for comment.Here the LinearLayout on the outermost spiral is 80dp high. If the TextView is filled with a long text I want it to scroll down. But with this code, scrollView does not work. I am using the same code in another layout and it works. I hope you understand my problem with this answer.